# Separate elements of array into two arrays

Tags: python

I did one simple code to separate elements of an array into two new arrays : one with odd numbers and other with even numbers. So I did this:

```
V=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
vp=[]
vi=[]
for x in V:
   if x%2==0:
      vp.append(x)
      V.remove(x)
   else:
      vi.append(x)
      V.remove(x)

print (V)
print (vp)
print (vi) # sorry for the bad identation first time sharing code here
```

and this code give me this result:

```
[2,4,6]
[]
[1,3,5]
```

How is it happen? How am I fix this?

Comment: What is your expected/desired output, precisely?

Comment: Your indentation looks fine, but your comment is invalid Python--it should start with `#` not `//`.

Comment: When you are iterating through a list with python, removing an item from that list will cause you to skip an item.

In this case you are iterating through V. So you end up modifying your list like so:

V[0] == 1
V[1]==2
V[2]==3
V.remove(0)
V[0]==2
V[1]==3

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove items from a list over which you are iterating. Use a copy:

```
V=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
vp=[]
vi=[]
for x in V[:]:
   if x%2==0:
      vp.append(x)
      V.remove(x)
   else:
      vi.append(x)
      V.remove(x)

print (V)
print (vp)
print (vi)
# []
# [2, 4, 6]
# [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: the third list is not necessary either, after removing evens the left over will be the complement set: odds.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't remove item while traversing an array:

```
V=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
vp=[]
vi=[]
for x in V:
 if x%2==0:
   vp.append(x)
 else:
  vi.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a `list` mid-iteration causes misbehavior (you effectively skip input elements). Don't `remove` from `V` as you go (which for long `V` would be expensive, each `remove` is `O(n)` making total work `O(n**2)`), just leave `V` unmodified. If necessary, clear `V` when you finish (a single `O(n)` operation), e.g. after the loop:

```
del V[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you remove items from a list, the list gets shorter. So when you're looping over a list in a forward direction, removing items will cause the the iterator to skip forward.

To mitigate this, you can loop backwards over a list and safely remove items, since you're removing them from the end.

```
V = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
vp = []
vi = []

# reverse the list before iterating
for x in reversed(V):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        vp.append(x)
        V.remove(x)
   else:
        vi.append(x)
        V.remove(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers that identified the problem and the fix, but here is a different way to do it using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
even = [e for e in numbers if e % 2 == 0]
odd = [e for e in numbers if e % 2 == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

A more concise way to make a new odd and even list from the original is to use comprehensions:

```
v = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
even = [number for number in v if number % 2 == 0]
odd = [number for number in v if number % 2 != 0]
```